# How to run PHP in the background using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a php form to a database, but I want that when I click the submit button the page refreshes itself (without having to go to the php page I'm submitting to). I understand I have to do this using JS, and I have tried a bunch of different ways without any success. I'm using three files, one for the form, one for the JS, and the last one to post the data into the database. I'm new to php and JS, any help will be very welcome, thanks.

PD here is the code I have so far:

**user.php**

```
  <head>
    ........

    <!--                       Javascripts                       -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/newuser.form_jquery.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      ...................................
          ......................................
                   ......................................

            <form action="" id="newuserform" method="post">
                <h4>New user</h4>
                <br /><br />

                <fieldset class="column-left">                  
                    <p>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="email" name="email" />

                        <br />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>First name</label>
                        <input class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />

                        <br />
                    </p>                    
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="column-right">
                    <p>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input class="text-input medium-input" type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />

                        <br />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />

                        <br />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>             
                    <p>
                        <input class="button" type="button" value="Create" id = "submit_btn"/>
                    </p>
                <div id="errormsg" class="notification error png_bg">
                    <div>
                        Invalid login, please check your username and password!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
                 </body>
```

**newuser.form_jquery.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#errormsg").hide();
     $("#newuserform").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        $("#errormsg").hide();
        jQuery('#submit_btn').focus().click();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});


$("#submit_butn").click( function() {


    var e = '#email';
    var p = '#pwd';
    var f = '#fname';
    var l = '#lname';

    var _e = $(e).val();
    var _p = $(p).val();
    var _f = $(f).val();
    var _l = $(l).val();


    var postFile = 'application/post.newuser.php';
    var dataurl = 'users';

    $.post(postFile, { e: _e, p: _p, f: _f, l: _l}, function(data) {
        if(data.status==true){
            window.location=dataurl;
        } else {

            $("#errormsg").show();

        }
    }

    ,'json');

});

    });
```

**post.newuser.php***

```
    public function newuser($e, $p, $f, $l)
{
    //e: email, p: password, f: first_name, l: last_name

    $return = false;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, first_name, last_name, role, enabled)";
    $sql .= " VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'".$e."', ";
    $sql .= "'".SHA1($p)."', ";
    $sql .= "'".$f."', ";
    $sql .= "'".$l."', ";
    $sql .= "'2', ";
    $sql .= "'1' ";
    $sql .= ")";

    $mysql = new mysql();
    $mysql->connect();
    $q = $mysql->queryin($sql);

    if ($q)
    {
        $return = true;
    } 

    $mysql->end(); 

    return $return;

}
```

Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try ajax
//in the php do what you wnt to do and return your value as json_decode($yourvariable)
//all json_decode does is transform your output into an array format. so that the function below can read it.

```
$.get("ajax.php", { id: hash }, //equivalent to ajax.php?id=hash

function(out)
{

}, "json");
```

check out how i used this on my site:
http://iadprint.com/products?product=product%201
(view source and scroll to the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do something in background you have to use AJAX so XMLHttpRequest object from JavaScript would serve you greate. You have to rebuild what you already have to use AJAX. It's pretty simle.
go to http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp and read what is there. It will take you something about 10 minutes to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the page refreshes back to itself is because you are not stopping the browser's default behavior of submitting a form. Here's what I would recommend doing.

```
$("#newuserform").submit(function(event) {
// handle processing

// stop the form from submitting since you used Ajax to submit
 event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

And I would consider it better coding practice to tie your JS code to the submit method rather than a click.

Also, while it's good you are hashing saved passwords, you are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://shiflett.org/articles/sql-injection). mysql_real_escape_string() is your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send information to a database and reload the page, you don't need JavaScript. Just add an if statement in the PHP document to see if $_POST[] is set and make sure you are submitting the data to the current page through the action attribute of .

Comment: Huh? Why would you recommend md5() over sha1()?

Comment: It's a long running debate. I won't go into details. But you should definitely salt the passwords before hashing them. May I direct you to good ole Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: MD5 is a weaker encryption algorithm than SHA-1. That's just a fact, there's not really anything to debate. They're both broken, and useless without salts anyway. I was curious why you'd recommend a weaker algorithm, rather than `bcrypt` or something.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I blindly accepted what I was told. I was told md5() was better than sha1(). With a quick Google search I find how wrong I am. Lol. Thanks for making me aware of that. :) Edited.